# heroku asset precompile timeout problems

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, jrubyonrails

We have a rails site that is expanding quite a bit.  it is using jruby, bootstrap, and some third party libraries - and the precompile takes a long time.  too long for the timeout limits on heroku for deployment.  is there a way to modify the timeout values so we'll be able to push our repository to heroku and have it precompile?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pre-compile locally and switch off heroku pre-compile?

Comment: that is the workaround we've come up with too but we'd ideally not have to do that as it's a PITA compared to letting them get precompiled on push.  

that does work however.  just not what we'd like to have to do.